# DataGridView scrollbar throwing ArgumentOutOfRange exception

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar

I have a form with a single DataGridView on it.  The DGV is bound to a DataTable and filled when the form loads with about 32,000 records.

If the user drags the scroll bar down and releases the mouse button when the mouse cursor is on the Down Arrow of the bottom of the scroll bar I get the exception listed below.

If the mouse button is released anywhere else like the bottom of the screen, down in the status bar, on the clock, no exception is thrown. You can then click on the last record and scroll back up.

Also, if you drag the scroll bar all the way down, release the mouse button in a 'safe' area, then you can scroll again and release the button on the down arrow and no exception is thrown.

All of my DataGridViews in the solution are setup with the same parameters. I have other DGV's with the same or more records and they do not do this.

About the Scrollbar Max Value Microsoft says: "The maximum value can only be reached programmatically. The value of a scroll bar cannot reach its maximum value through user interaction at run time."

I am not manipulating any of the scroll bar values in code.

I cannot find anything anywhere about this.  I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction for troubleshooting this problem.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled   Message=Value of
'2612103' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between
'minimum' and 'maximum'. Parameter name: Value  
Source=System.Windows.Forms   ParamName=Value   StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBar.set_Value(Int32 value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBar.DoScroll(ScrollEventType type)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBar.WmReflectScroll(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBar.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr aram, IntPtr lparam)        at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd,
Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(IntPtr hWnd, Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr
wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBar.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at VWBSMS.Program.Main() in C:\Documents and Settings\courtp\My Documents\Development\C++_DLL_Projects\VWBSMS\VWBSMS\MDIForms\Program.cs:line
21
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
activationContext)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:
```

Grid View

```
    this.dtGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    this.dtGrid.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    this.dtGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    this.dtGrid.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
    this.dtGrid.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
    this.idCol,
    this.lineColumn,
    this.lineCol,
    this.eqpCol,
    this.minColumn,
    this.eqptColumn,
    this.rpNameCol,
    this.malCol,
    this.solutionColumn,
    this.ltColumn,
    this.faultColumn,
    this.originatorCol,
    this.dateCol,
    this.timeDownCol,
    this.dateUpCol,
    this.timeUpCol,
    this.T2ID,
    this.T1ID,
    this.threeCodeCol,
    this.respCol});
    this.dtGrid.ContextMenuStrip = this.gvContextMenut;
    this.dtGrid.DataSource = this.dTMPNewBindingSource;
    this.dtGrid.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.dtGrid.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.dtGrid.Name = "dtGrid";
    this.dtGrid.ReadOnly = true;
    this.dtGrid.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    this.dtGrid.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(980, 360);
    this.dtGrid.TabIndex = 115;
```

Base Class Formatting that all gridviews are passed.

```
        dgvA.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dgvA.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        dgvA.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
        dgvA.AllowUserToResizeColumns = true;
        dgvA.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
        dgvA.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
        dgvA.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders;

        // Main Grid Settings
        dgvA.BackgroundColor = SystemColors.Control;
        dgvA.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        dgvA.GridColor = SystemColors.ActiveBorder;
  // ************* Column Headers **********************
            // General Settings
            dgvA.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Raised;
            dgvA.ColumnHeadersHeight = 20;  // Based on a Tahoma font of 9
            dgvA.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;
            dgvA.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            dgvA.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = true;


            // Column Headers Default Cell Style
            dgvA.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment =             DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            dgvA.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            dgvA.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
            dgvA.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = SystemColors.MenuHighlight;
            dgvA.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
            // ********************** ROWS  ************************
            // Alternating Rows Default Cell Style
            dgvA.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Info;
            dgvA.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;


            // Row Headers 
            dgvA.RowHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Raised;
            dgvA.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            dgvA.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            dgvA.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
            dgvA.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
            dgvA.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
            dgvA.RowHeadersVisible = false;

            // ************* Default Cell Style  ******************
            dgvA.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            dgvA.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
            dgvA.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
            dgvA.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
            dgvA.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
            dgvA.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

Which is set Here in the constructor

```
    base.gridThemeSet(dtGrid);

    DataGridViewCellStyle myStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();

    myStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;


    malCol.DefaultCellStyle = myStyle;
```

Comment: I have a feeling that we need to see some of your code to make a diagnosis.

Comment: Update: I have masked the problem by changing the size of the Panel that the data grid is in and moving it away from the edges of the form.   @James. I am not sure what code to add. I dont think the problem is in the code for the DGV, its all generated.  What code would you like to see?

Comment: Added the gridview construction and formatting code.  I have had several people look at this and we cant come up with a solution other than to adjust the formatting of the Gridview in relation to the form. This problem violates the exception rule "The value of a scroll bar cannot reach its maximum value through user interaction at run time" so I don't think its in the c# code, I may be wrong but as of yet we haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: I just ran into this problem as well, or something similar. `PerformLayout` did resolve it for me however.

Answer (score 4):

Try calling dataGridView.PerformLayout(); after the data is loaded or bound.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/csharpgeneral/thread/2dc39584-d833-4989-bb70-9b616a9daf4b

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/hr-HR/Offtopic/thread/0b091621-34a5-45e4-a37c-c7e18a767a26

Comment: I tried that before I posted and it still threw the exception.

Answer (score 1):

dataGridView.PerformLayout(); usually solves this problem, but if it doesn't work, just make sure that the insertions and deletions of columns in your dataGrid are done while it is active (enabled) and it will refresh by itself correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I work arround this by recreating the datagridview control with code from the form designer cs file:

```
private void DgvInit(){
    var dgvs=dataGridView1.Size;
    SuspendLayout();
    dis:try{
        dataGridView1.Dispose();
    } catch{goto dis;}
    Controls.Remove(dataGridView1);
    dataGridView1=new DataGridView();
    ((ISupportInitialize)(dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
    dataGridView1.Anchor = ((AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom) | AnchorStyles.Left) | AnchorStyles.Right;
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
    dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
    dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
    dataGridView1.Location = new Point(12, 28);
    dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
    dataGridView1.Size=dgvs;
    dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
    Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
    ((ISupportInitialize)(dataGridView1)).EndInit();
    ResumeLayout(true);
}
```

If the DGV is likely to be resized you will need to store the Size and assign it again.

The goto fixes some bugs with the datagridview, it looks like it may cause an infinite loop when an exception occurs at dispose but it has not as far as I have tested.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error message occuring on scroll down, had some trouble to fix it.

finally the problem was that i had a database table bound via datatable to the datagrid, the db table had a column varchar(30) and i wrote some strings programmatically in this columns' cells. these string had a length up to 50.

it was kinda weird that the error occured on scroll and not when i change the datatables values. also the message gave no useful information.

so for other people getting this error: check if all your data has the correct datatype and length.

Comment: Never thought of that. I will go back and look. Thanks.